# How can i improve this query for better performance on Oracle

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Products

```
product_id  product_serial_number   product_status
1           X123                    PENDING
1           X123                    PROCESSED
2           X345                    PENDING
3           X678                    PENDING
4           Y890                    PENDING
4           Y890                    PROCESSED
```

The above table shows the status of a product and its history. I need to produce a report with the output to be as shown below:

```
product_id  status
1           UPDATE
2           NEW
3           NEW
4           UPDATE
```

I.e. if a product has previously been processed (e.g. products 1 and 4) its status is UPDATE otherwise its status is NEW.

I have come up with this query but i am not happy with its performance:

```
select product_id, 'UPDATE'
from products p1
where product_id in (select product_id from products p2 where p2.product_status='PROCESSED' and p2.product_status='ARCHIVED')
Union
select product_id, 'NEW'
from products p1
where product_id not in (select product_id from products p2 where p2.product_status='PROCESSED' and p2.product_status='ARCHIVED')
```

Another approach that could also work is to join the table to itself:

```
select p1.product_id, decode(p2.product_id, null, 'NEW','UPDATE')
from products p1, products p2
where p1.product_id=p2.product_id(+)
and p1.product_serial_number=p2.serial_number(+)
and p2.product_status(+) = 'PROCESSED'
```

When either of the queries are run against a large data set, the performance is not very good. How can i improve (or even change completely) the above queries for best performance?

Comment: Your sample data has product #1 as previously processed, implying that its current status is "PENDING" and its previous status is "PROCESSED". How do you determine which is current? Is there are date or timestamp column involved? And are PENDING and PROCESSED the only status codes you're dealing with?

Comment: There can only be three statuses ARCHIVED - PROCESSED - PENDING. If a new row is inserted for the same product the status are cycled. i.e. The row with ARCHIVED status is deleted. Row with PROCESSED status becomes ARCHIVED, PENDING becomes PROCESSED and the new row is inserted with a PENDING status. There can never be more than 3 rows for each product.

Comment: OK, got it. If a product is brand new (no rows for the product in the table yet) and a row is added, is the new row's status PENDING?

Comment: Yes a new row is inserted with status of PENDING if it is a new product.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT product_id, (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 'NEW' ELSE 'UPDATED' END) status
FROM products
WHERE product_status <> 'ARCHIVED'
GROUP BY product_id
```

Check out other `GROUP BY` [aggregate functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions003.htm).

**Edit**

Fixed issue with [Case expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions004.htm) syntax. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is this syntax valid for Oracle as i cant get it to work on Oracle 11G

Comment: @ziggy - I updated the query to use `CASE` instead of `IF` after looking into Oracle 11G syntax specifically.

Comment: @aiias you'll need to close the CASE: `(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 'NEW' ELSE 'UPDATED' END) status` - note the `END` right before the closing parentheses. The outer parentheses around the CASE are optional BTW.

Comment: @graceemile - Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: No worries @aiias - I leave out the END pretty regularly :)  @ziggy - the ARCHIVED status didn't come up until after aiias answered so remember to add a `WHERE product_status <> 'ARCHIVED'` to aiias's answer when you try this at home.

Comment: @graceemile - I have added your suggestion for ignoring archived products.

Answer (score 1):

You *may* get better speed using MINUS and INTERSECT, which are overlooked cousins of UNION.

All the products that have a PENDING and a PROCESSED row:

```
SELECT product_id FROM Products WHERE product_status = 'PENDING'
INTERSECT SELECT product_id FROM Products WHERE product_status = 'PROCESSED'
```

All the products that have a PENDING row but not a PROCESSED row:

```
SELECT product_id FROM Products WHERE product_status = 'PENDING'
MINUS SELECT product_id FROM Products WHERE product_status = 'PROCESSED'
```

Put them together (and add the NEW/UPDATE):

```
SELECT product_id, 'NEW' FROM (
   SELECT product_id FROM Products WHERE product_status = 'PENDING'
   MINUS SELECT product_id FROM Products WHERE product_status = 'PROCESSED')
UNION
SELECT product_id, 'UPDATE' FROM (
  SELECT product_id FROM Products WHERE product_status = 'PENDING'
  INTERSECT SELECT product_id FROM Products WHERE product_status = 'PROCESSED')
```

For a large table you're going to have at least 2/3 of the rows involved so the query will never be super fast.

If you plan to run this query a lot, you may also want to consider an index on `product_status`.

Comment: Querying the same table multiple times - whatever operations we use to assemble the result set - will almost always be slower than querying it once.

Comment: @APC - I agree. It's just that I've had freakishly good luck with MINUS and INTERSECT before. I'm 99% sure the answer from aiias (altered to ignore the ARCHIVED status) will be faster, but I figured the INTERSECT/MINUS was worth trying, just in case. Like you said, "almost always" :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with CTE as
(
   select product_id, decode(product_status,'PROCESSED','UPDATE','NEW') status,
   row_number() over (partition by product_id
   order by decode(product_status,'PROCESSED','UPDATE','NEW') desc) rnum
   from products p1
)
select * from cte where rnum = 1
```

Comment: This solution works if there are no more than two rows per `product_id`.  So it fits the posted data.  Obviously it is adaptable to whatever number of values `product_status` has in real life.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answers (I like the one about INTERSECT anв MINUS).

For very small quantity of the possible values of field 'product_status' an ordinary indexes (based on B-Tree) aren't working well. You need to use a bitmap index on this field.
[Oracle Bitmap Index Techniques](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_bitmapped_indexes.htm)
[CREATE INDEX in Oracle Docs - search for bitmap](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5012.htm)